# Making a step-by-step ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, jquery

I'm thinking about how to change a content of a div dynamically. So, here is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/foos',
    cache: false,
    type: 'get',

}).done( function( foo_array ) {
    for( foo in foo_array ) {
        $('#foo-container').append('<div class="foo-var">'+foo+'</div>');
    }
});
```

So bassically, this ajax append all foo-var divs from the server, but if the foo_array is too long or a big very big array there is a problem because i think that takes more and more time depending on the foo_array's length

How can I append one by one??, how can I query one by one and append in foo-container instead query all foos and make an iteration??

I want to do something like this

```
if(foos.hasNext()){ $.ajax..... append(foo)....}
```

foos is an array made by many documents from a mongodb database, so I cant get the length of the array because depends of the query's find() arguments..

I'm using nodejs, mongodb, expressjs and jquery for ajax

Sorry for my bad English, and thank you all!

EDIT 2

this is an example of the data in mongodb

```
{category:1, name:'robert',personal:true,option:'class'}
{category:1, name:'alfredo',personal:false,option:'class'}
{category:4, name:'ricardo',personal:true,option:'class'}
{category:1, name:'genaro',personal:true,option:'class'}
{category:2, name:'andres',personal:false,option:'class'}
{category:1, name:'jose',personal:true,option:'class'}


db.collection.find({personal:true}) // gives me 4 documents
db.collection.find({option:'class'}) // gives me 6 documents
db.collection.find({category:4}) // gives me 1 document
```

i dont know how many documents can get from the cursor, i need to charge one by one cause there are 5097841 documents in the databse so, ajax can take long time to return all the information, i need to query one by one if hasNext() in the cursor of mongodb

Comment: I would suggest some kind of paging, where you load 10-15 items per request

Comment: i cant use paging, i have to charge all documents from the database

Comment: if `foo_array` is truly an array you don't want to use `for/in`.  Show sample of data. Comment regarding paging can also be done by multiple AJAX requests `$.each` is easy to implement  http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: can i use socket.io to do this?? im reading many ways to send vars on socket.io

Comment: There might be multiple apporaches to solve this problem. (1) Database based pagination where you maintain a starting index and end index of the data on the client side. You send these indexes to get the next set of data (2) Server Side Pagination where you get all the data from Database and do the subsequent fetches (3) Javascript based pagination - You have to test its performance. Store the array as Javascript object and retrieve based on the last index fetched

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip and limit and can make multiple requests. It's like paging.The following syntax may help you

db.collection.find().skip(200).limit(100);